# Discord py - music bot queue command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Hey guys,**

I have two little problems I dont know how to solve.

**What do I want to do?**

I want to create a pretty simple music bot with a few functions.

1. Play music from a URL
2. Play music from a Title
3. Play music from a Queue

Now my problems:

Everytime I use

> ?play TITLE or URL

it skips the currently playing song - I want the bot to wait until the song is finished

and my second problem is pretty much the same - I want the bot to play a queue and wait until every song is finished - now he loops through the list of songs and only plays the first :(

**What does my code look like:**

```py
import discord
import asyncio
import os
import youtube_dl

import urllib.parse, urllib.request, re
import requests

from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Embed, FFmpegPCMAudio
from discord.utils import get

'''

INSTALLING YOUTUBE-DL

pip install -U git+https://github.com/l1ving/youtube-dl

'''

queue = []

youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''

ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0'
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)

class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False, play=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream or play))

        if 'entries' in data:
            data = data['entries'][0]

        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)


class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):

        if not ctx.message.author.voice:
            await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel!")
            return
        else:
            channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
            await ctx.send(f'Connected to ``{channel}``')

        await channel.connect()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url):

        try:

            async with ctx.typing():
                player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True)
                ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)

            await ctx.send(f':mag_right: **Searching for** ``' + url + '``\n<:youtube:763374159567781890> **Now Playing:** ``{}'.format(player.title) + "``")

        except:

            await ctx.send("Somenthing went wrong - please try again later!")

    @commands.command()
    async def play_queue(self, ctx):

        for url in queue:

            try:

                async with ctx.typing():
                    player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True)
                    ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)

                await ctx.send(f'<:youtube:763374159567781890> **Now Playing:** ``{url}``')

            except:

                await ctx.send("Somenthing went wrong - please try again later!")
            
        else:

            await ctx.send("Queue is now done!")

    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self, ctx):
        voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

        voice.pause()

        user = ctx.message.author.mention
        await ctx.send(f"Bot was paused by {user}")

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self, ctx):
        voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

        voice.resume()

        user = ctx.message.author.mention
        await ctx.send(f"Bot was resumed by {user}")

    @commands.command()
    async def add_queue(self, ctx, url):

        global queue

        try:
            queue.append(url)
            user = ctx.message.author.mention
            await ctx.send(f'``{url}`` was added to the queue by {user}!')
        except:
            await ctx.send(f"Couldnt add {url} to the queue!")

    @commands.command()
    async def remove_queue(self, ctx, number):

        global queue

        try:
            del(queue[int(number)])
            if len(queue) < 1:
                await ctx.send("Your queue is empty now!")
            else:
                await ctx.send(f'Your queue is now {queue}')
        except:
            await ctx.send("List index out of range - the queue starts at 0")

    @commands.command()
    async def clear_queue(self, ctx):

        global queue

        queue.clear()
        user = ctx.message.author.mention
        await ctx.send(f"The queue was cleared by {user}")

    @commands.command()
    async def view_queue(self, ctx):

        if len(queue) < 1:
            await ctx.send("The queue is empty - nothing to see here!")
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'Your queue is now {queue}')

    @commands.command()
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
        user = ctx.message.author.mention
        await voice_client.disconnect()
        await ctx.send(f'Disconnected from {user}')

    @play_queue.before_invoke
    @play.before_invoke
    async def ensure_voice(self, ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            if ctx.author.voice:
                await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
            else:
                await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel.")
                raise commands.CommandError("Author not connected to a voice channel.")
        elif ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
            ctx.voice_client.stop()

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Music(client))
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I just want to say that you really described your issue very well, and everything is really well organized, nice job!

Answer (score 1):

So I think what you need to do is to split the `play` and `play_queue` functions completely into a `play` and `start_playing` functions.

What I mean by this is currently your play command finds a song and plays it, when what it should be doing is finding a song and appending it to a queue, so the process should look something like this:

1. Someone types `play 'song'`
2. The bot checks if no songs are playing `if len(self.queue) == 0: start_playing(song)`, if so it calls a function which starts playing the song, if there are songs playing it adds it to to the queue, the way I would suggest doing this would be to give each song an id, `self.queue[len(self.queue)] = song`
3. Then if someone uses the `play 'song'` command again the song is added to the queue and played once the first song is finished

Essentially I'm suggesting the `play_queue` command be removed, the `play` to be turned into a play if no songs are playing otherwise add to queue command, and a function which is called when no songs are playing

The implementation of `self.queue` might look like this:

```py
@commands.command()
async def join(self, ctx):

    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel!")
        return
    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        self.queue = {}
        await ctx.send(f'Connected to ``{channel}``')

    await channel.connect()

@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx, *, url):

    try:

        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True)

            if len(self.queue) == 0:

                self.start_playing(ctx.voice_client, player)
                await ctx.send(f':mag_right: **Searching for** ``' + url + '``\n<:youtube:763374159567781890> **Now Playing:** ``{}'.format(player.title) + "``")

            else:
                
                self.queue[len(self.queue)] = player
                await ctx.send(f':mag_right: **Searching for** ``' + url + '``\n<:youtube:763374159567781890> **Added to queue:** ``{}'.format(player.title) + "``")

    except:

        await ctx.send("Somenthing went wrong - please try again later!")

def start_playing(self, voice_client, player):

    self.queue[0] = player

    i = 0
    while i <  len(self.queue):
        try:
            voice_client.play(self.queue[i], after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)

        except:
            pass
        i += 1
```

This should solve both the play and play queue problems

Comment: Thanks for the code, but now the bot cant play the song anymore. He instantly goes into the "except: await ctx.send("Somenthing went wrong - please try again later!")" :/ - but I do not get any errors ?

Comment: Remove the try and except statements and see the error

Comment: I dont get any errors - it just doesnt play the song ?

Comment: I added `self.queue = queue` to the top in the class. Or did I forget anything?

Comment: I can't say for sure. what did you change?

Comment: I just copied the "play" command and added `self.queue = queue` to `def __init__` in the **Music** class. I also removed my `play_queue`command

Comment: Oh ok, because all the code I mentioned in my answer include changes, try adding in all of it

Comment: Oh sorry I didnt notice that you also edited `join` - now I got the problem that he says `ERROR: 1F6pkvFFCVI: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data` - I read that it has to do with cookies right? Do you now how to **fast** fix this?