# Bot Discord Python Queue System

Tags: list, discord.py, queue, bots

**hello guys**

I have 1 problem that seems very usual, so i wanted to make queue system on my music bot discord using lists.
I see a similar question from stack overflow too [Discord py - music bot queue command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64748660/discord-py-music-bot-queue-command),in this site I copied the answers and change a little bit to my code.

But then i tried to play some music, it show error like this
`IndexError : list assigment index out of range`

**What does my code look like:**

```py
queue = [] 
class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.queue = queue

    @bot.command(name='join', help='Tells the bot to join the voice channel')
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if not ctx.message.author.voice:
            await ctx.send("{} tidak terkonek ke voice channel".format(ctx.message.author.name))
            return
        else:
            channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
            self.queue = {}
            await ctx.send(f'Connected to ``{channel}``')

        await channel.connect()

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Music cog successfully loaded.')

    @bot.command(name='p', help='To play song')
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url): #im not using try: and except: because its always skips the 'try': part
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice_client = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        
        if voice_client is not None:
            if not voice_client.is_connected():
                voice_client = await channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"konekin ke {ctx.message.author.voice.channel} voice channel")
            try:
                voice_client = await channel.connect()
                await ctx.send(f"sudah konek ke {ctx.message.author.voice.channel} voice channel")
            except Exception as e:
                await ctx.send(e)

        async with ctx.typing():
        
            filename = await YT_dlpSource.from_url(url)
            if len(self.queue) == 0:

                self.start_playing(ctx.voice_client, filename)
                await ctx.send(f' **Searching for** ``' + url + '``\n **Now Playing:** ``{}'.format(filename.title) + "``")

            else:
                self.queue[len(self.queue)] = filename
                await ctx.send(f' **Searching for** ``' + url + '``\n **Now Playing:** ``{}'.format(filename.title) + "``")
    
        await ctx.send("Somenthing went wrong - please try again later!")

    def start_playing(self, voice_client, filename):
        self.queue[0] = filename
        i = 0
        while i < len(self.queue):
            try:
                voice_client.play(self.queue[i], after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)
            except:
                pass
            i += 1
```

**And the error shows:**

```
Ignoring exception in command p:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/User/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/User/DISCOBOT/discord/cogs/music.py", line 104, in play
    self.start_playing(ctx.voice_client, filename)
  File "/home/User/DISCOBOT/discord/cogs/music.py", line 116, in start_playing
    self.queue[0] = filename
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/User/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/Najwan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/User/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the value of self.queue is empty, i.e., it has no index or items.

Instead of doing this: `self.queue[0] = filename`

Do this: `self.queue.append(filename)`